# Tkinter store entry box value as value for other file

Tags: python, tkinter, box, tkinter-entry

This is my first python personal project.  I am wanting to use Tkinter to create a window (GUARDIAN LOCATOR) that asks the user to input a value (enter sailor guardian) into the entry box.  The rest of the program is dependent on what the user types in the entry box as I will be having if/else statements reacting to the sailor guardian entered.

The issue I am having is storing what is entered in the entry box as a variable to use in my main file for the if/else statements.  I can get the value to print to the prompt window, but I haven't been able to store it successfully to a global variable.

My Tkinter window is in it's own class.

I have tried many different ways of doing this based on similar issues from stackoverflow, but I am getting an error every time.   This is my base code that still produces the error.

## Class file with the Tkinter window

```
class GuardianLocator:

def __init__(self, master):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.grid()
    master.title("GUARDIAN LOCATOR")

    self.locator_label = Label(frame, text="Which Sailor Guardian are you looking for?", width=40, height=2)
    self.locator_label.grid()

    self.entry = Entry(frame)
    self.entry.grid()

    self.button1 = Button(frame, text="Search", command=self.guardian_name, pady=2)
    self.button1.grid()

def guardian_name(self):
    print(self.entry.get())
```

## and in my main working file

```
root = Tk()
locator = guardian_locator.GuardianLocator(root)

root.mainloop()
```

## This is my test loop to see if it's working.

```
if locator.guardian_input() is "Sailor Moon":
    print("hi")
else:
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly how your code is organized and where is your "test loop" located, but I assume it is after `root.mainloop()`. Thus the script can be as follows:

```
from tkinter import *


class GuardianLocator:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self._name = "" 
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.grid()
        master.title("GUARDIAN LOCATOR")

        self.locator_label = Label(frame, text="Which Sailor Guardian are you looking for?", width=40, height=2)
        self.locator_label.grid()

        self.entry = Entry(frame)
        self.entry.grid()

        self.button1 = Button(frame, text="Search", command=self.guardian_name, pady=2)
        self.button1.grid()

    def guardian_name(self):
        self._name = self.entry.get()
        print(self.entry.get())


root = Tk()
locator = GuardianLocator(root)

root.mainloop()

# this will be executed after the root window is closed.
print("Name is", locator._name)
```

Please note `self._name = ""` in the constructor. This instance variable can be used to store the name provided in your GuardianLocator window.

Comment: Omgosh that works! I tried doing a very similar method earlier but I must've screwed it up somehow.  Thank you Marcin!

Comment: @djohnson129 If anwser is good, that accepting it would be good as well:-)

Comment: If you meant clicking the checkmark, I just did.  I didn't know about that yet :/